# Changing CSS properties on focus

Tags: jquery, html, css, focus, border

Is there a way to change the CSS border of a div, when an input field gets focus (e.g. when it loses focus, remove the border).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="title" id="title"></input>
<div id="mainTitle">The Main Title</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainTitle {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$(function() {      //aka document.ready
    $("input#title").focus( function() {
        $("div#mainTitle").css("border","1px solid #ccc");
    });

    $("input#title").blur( function() {
        $("div#mainTitle").css("border","");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use css, if your users are working in a competent browser (so, not IE, for the most part):

```
input:hover + #mainTitle,
input:focus + #mainTitle,
input:active + #mainTitle {
   border: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: most of my users use IE lol, :)) i wish that would work IE :((